# Is there a good way to systematically remove items from one list and add to another one at a time?

Tags: apex

Trying:

```
List<sObject> list1 = New List<sObject>(has values);  
List<sObject> list2 = New List<sObject>(has no values);  
for (Integer i=0; i<5; i++) {  
    sObject toAdd = list1[i].remove;  
    list2.add(toAdd);
}
```

Comment: sry i can't edit. Trying to figure it out..

Comment: I've edited your question this time. For future reference, you can use backticks (the key to the left of the `1` key on English qwerty keyboards) to 'inline' code. To make a code block (like I've done for you), each line needs to have 4 spaces at the beginning of the line (plus an empty line above & below). The easiest way to do that is to highlight your code and press `ctrl + k` (alternatively, pressing the `{}` button on the top bar of the text editor does the same thing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close:

```
for(Integer i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    list2.add(list1.remove(i));
}
```

Keep in mind that if your objective is to copy the first five elements, you should count backwards:

```
for(Integer i = 4; i >= 0; i--) {
```

Otherwise, you'd end up copying the first, third, fifth, seventh, and ninth element instead.

List.remove returns the element that was removed, so there's no need for an intermediary to hold the value while it transitions from one list to the other.

If you want to retain the original order of those elements, remove the zeroth element each time:

```
for(Integer i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    list2.add(list1.remove(0));
}
```

Or pre-initialize the list and copy the values if you'd like to count backwards, as above:

```
list2 = new SObject[5];
for(Integer i = 4; i >= 0; i--) {
    list2[i] = list1.remove(i);
}
```

Comment: Great thanks! This remove will also take off of the first list correct? so after removing list1.remove(0) then will 0 be null? or shift?

Comment: @AndrewMayes Yes, remove removes the current element and shifts all elements higher than the removed index down one, and the list's size will be one smaller.

Comment: I see now. That is why you should count backwards

Comment: @AndrewMayes Yes. If the order matters, note that counting backwards would reverse those five elements. If you want the same order, just remove the zeroth element for each of the five times in your loop.